# Послать сообщение из php в js

Tags: php, javascript

Необходимо отслеживать момент подключения удалёного свитча на сервер и вывести сообщение в браузер. Возможно из php-скрипта отправить что-то напрямую в javascript на индексной странице? Как ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, эта статья Вам поможет: [Socket-соединения в Веб-приложениях](http://habrahabr.ru/post/41223/).

Answer (score 2):

Из РНР напрямую в JS без того, чтобы он знал об этом никак. Можно сделать функцию в JS, которая будет периодически асинхронно посылать в AJAX запрос в РНР скрипт и получать какой-нибудь ответ.